# Behavior like tools:text in a custom view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-xml

I have a custom view with two text views in the layout. Let's call one `key` and the other `value`.

So you know how `TextView` has this?

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="Preview text shown in the layout editor" />
```

I want to do something similar with my custom view, e.g.:

```
<com.package.whatever.MyCustomView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:key_preview="Preview text for the key"
    app:value_preview="Preview text for the value" />
```

The constructor for `MyCustomView` is like so:

```
public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
            .inflate(R.layout.my_custom_view, this, true);

    key = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.key);
    value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.value);

    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyCustomView, 0, 0);
    try {
        if (isInEditMode()) {
            key.setText(a.getText(R.styleable.MyCustomView_key_preview));
            value.setText(a.getText(R.styleable.MyCustomView_value_preview));
        }
        key.setText(a.getText(R.styleable.MyCustomView_key));
        value.setText(a.getText(R.styleable.MyCustomView_value));
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }
}
```

And `attrs.xml`:

```
<declare-styleable name="MyCustomView">
    <attr name="key" format="string" />
    <attr name="key_preview" format="string" />
    <attr name="value" format="string" />
    <attr name="value_preview" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

**The issue** is that `isInEditMode()` is returning `false` when I view a layout which includes `MyCustomView` in the layout editor. If I add `app:key="yay"` it works fine, but for `app:key_preview="nay :("` nothing shows up.

What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a dingus and lied to you all. `isInEditMode()` was not returning false.

*cough cough*:

```
    if (isInEditMode()) {
        key.setText(a.getText(R.styleable.MyCustomView_key_preview));
        value.setText(a.getText(R.styleable.MyCustomView_value_preview));
    } else {
        key.setText(a.getText(R.styleable.MyCustomView_key));
        value.setText(a.getText(R.styleable.MyCustomView_value));
    }
```

Turns out what I had initially was in fact setting the key to be the value of `app:key_preview`, however it was then subsequently overwritten with the `null` that `a.getText(R.styleable.MyCustomView_key)` was returning.

voopz.

Comment: alternatively, you could use an if/else statement. that would be cleaner.