# How to support "tools:text" in a new custom view ?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-custom-view

### Background

There are ways for developers to set various `tools:` attribute for known Views in XML, so that they will appear only in edit mode (on the IDE) and not at runtime:

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#tools_instead_of_android

So, if you have a TextView, you can set `tools:text="hello"` , and this will be shown only in the IDE.

### The problem

While I use this nice feature for quite some time, I've found no documentation of how to create such attributes, or let my own custom view support them (either existing or new ones).

### What I've tried

I tried to reach those attributes like normal ones, but I don't think it's possible (or I just did it wrong).

What I do know for a very long time, is that I can use [**View.isInEditMode**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#isInEditMode()) to check if the code is now running on the IDE. But that's just a tiny step.

### The questions

1. Given I have a custom View that I've made, how can I make it support existing possible `tools:` attributes? For example, suppose I don't extend from TextView, but I do wish to support `tools:text` , how do I do it?
2. How can I create new `tools:` attributes for my custom views  ?

Comment: have u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42770383/behavior-like-toolstext-in-a-custom-view

Comment: @NileshRathod That's not the same. It uses normal attributes I can already create. I'm asking about `tools:`  .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to use existing `tools:` attributes in you custom views, all you have to do is to add those attributes to your `<declare-stleable>`:

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomView">
    <!-- This will allow you to use tools:text attribute as well -->
    <attr name="android:text"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

In your custom view you can get the attribute like this:

```
a.getText(R.styleable.CustomView_android_text)
```

Now you can do this:

```
<com.myapplication.CustomView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="Lorem ipsum"/>
```

This will allow you to use standard `tools:` attributes in your custom views. If you'd like to define your own design-time attributes, [I've written a small library that allows you to do that](https://github.com/paulmanta/app-tools-attrs).

Comment: So it's not possible without the library ? Too bad. But since you got it all covered, thank you. You got your V and +1 for effort